# Code a table with no rows, but just one column

Tags: html, html-helper

I have a HTML table. It has 3 columns. The first column is `name`. 2nd is `School` and 3rd is `HomeAddress`.

The table loads records from the DB, therefore the number of rows may vary from time to time. The 3rd Column (`HomeAddress`) should have no rows, while the other 2 columns (`name` and `school`) can have more rows. How should i model the HTML table to have the 3rd column with no rows ?

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            School
        </th>
        <th>
            Home Address
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var i in Model.allPpl)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.school)


        </td>
        <td>
            // THERE SHOULDN'T BE ANY ROWS FOR THIS COLUMN, JUST ONE COLUMN FOR THE WHOLE TABLE
        </td>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: Your question is not the least bit clear. Do you want what the good ole' `rowSpan="numrows"` attribute for the `td` element does? That - as the name says - makes one cell span multiple rows. You'll have to find out how many rows you have though to be able to use this.

Comment: Yes i need something like rowspan. but not sure where to add it. There should be 3 columns, and last column should have no rows.

Comment: As mentioned by @ppeterka rowspan should do what you need. You should count the rows and then add the needed rowspan.

Comment: you have to use rowspan in your last td..give rowspan="num of rows of your result"

Comment: What hapence if i don't know the number of rows in advance ? then how should use rowspan ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rowspan](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp) attribute is your only friend.

Try `<td rowspan="rowcount"></td>` for third column where rowcount is the no. of rows returned.

And modify your foreach loop as follows:

```
 @bool flag=false;
 @foreach (var i in Model.allPpl)
 {
  <tr>
     <td>
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.school)


    </td>
    if(!flag){
    <td rowspan="@Model.allPpl.count">
        // THERE SHOULDN'T BE ANY ROWS FOR THIS COLUMN, JUST ONE COLUMN FOR THE WHOLE TABLE
    </td>
     }flag=true;
</tr>
}
```

Note: I haven't tested this razor view code so please take care of compiler error if shows any.

Answer (score 0):

I think these entries will help you:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp